# Bounded completely monotone function has bounded derivative

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Suppose $f\colon (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ admits derivatives of all orders on $(0,1)$ and is *completely monotone*: $$ (-1)^n f^{(n)}(x) \ge 0 \quad \text{for all $x\in (0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N} \,\cup\, \{0\}$.}$$
Suppose further that $f(0) := \lim_{x \searrow 0} f(x) < \infty.$

I want to show that the limit of the first derivative $f'(0) := \lim_{x \searrow 0} f'(x)$ is finite; but so far, I could not think of a proof. I am sure that it would have to depend on the facts that $f(0) < \infty$ and that $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: What's the point of $(0,1]?$

Comment: Maybe this is useful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

Comment: Is $0\in \mathbb N?$

Comment: Could also be $(0,1).$ I thought the proof would look nicer if one could use $f(1).$

Comment: Yes, $f(x) \ge 0.$ I clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x)=1-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: That doesn't work because $f'(x)>0.$ However, $1-\sqrt x$ looks good ...

Comment: Oh dear, you are right. $1-\sqrt{x}$ is a counterexample.